# Angular 4 AOT compiler does not support mixins

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli

Sometimes I use Mixins to inject repeated functions like `slugUrl()`.

But it doesn't work with angular 4 compiler.

```
export function Mixin(decorators: Function[]) {
  return function (classFn: Function) {
    decorators.forEach(decorator => {
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(decorator.prototype).forEach(name => {
        classFn.prototype[name] = decorator.prototype[name];
      });
    });
  };
}


@Mixin([BehaviorInjected])
export class FooComponent {

}
```

If I compile this code, compiler throws:

> Property 'ngClassControl' does not exist on type 'FooComponent'.

Any ideas?

Edit: Since there was someone who asked, here's another example using TS mixins that reproduces the issue, this time at template level.

Components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    template: '<test [tag]="tag"></test>'
})
export class HomePageComponent extends TaggedComponent(MyComponent) {
    public tag = 'hi there';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class TestComponent extends TaggedComponent(MyComponent) {}
```

Mixins:

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

export function TaggedComponent<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
     class TaggedBase extends Base {
        @Input() tag: string;
     };

     return TaggedBase;
}

export class MyComponent {
    protected subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();
  // ...
}
```

Error:

> ERROR in Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'tag' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'test'. ("][tag]="tag">")

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I disabled mixins... there's no choice.

Comment: I added a bounty. I'm hoping that there is one and we're both uninformed, I couldn't manage to find anything either.

Comment: Do you have any reproduction?

Comment: @yurzui Added to the question.

Comment: Hi, the "only" annotations supported by the AOT compiler are listed in the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/metadata#annotationsdecorators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that angular compiler has limited functionality.(read more in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/metadata#angular-metadata-and-aot))

AOT compiler uses metadata that is generated by MetadataCollector. It uses typescript object model(tree of `Node`)(**that's why AOT can be used only with typescript**) to gather all information that is necessary to produce `ngfactory` (in some cases also `ngsummary`) files.

The examples you provided are completely different for AOT compiler:

1) Custom decorator

```
@Mixin([BehaviorInjected])
export class FooComponent {}
```

Angular [`MetadataCollector`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.ts#L46) will include `@Mixin` decorator in metadata of `FooComponent` symbol(item in `decorators` array) but it [will be skipped](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/aot/static_reflector.ts#L564-L584) when aot `StaticReflector` will call `simplify` since `Mixin` decorator is not registered in special map that includes only strictly defined decorators (**[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/aot/static_reflector.ts#L279-L320)**)

Moreover if we even include it in that map it still won't be executed during aot compilation because it is only available for supported decorators.

2) Call custom function

```
export class HomePageComponent extends TaggedComponent(MyComponent) {
```

`MetadataCollector` [will add](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.ts#L126-L135) `TaggedComponent` to metadata collection as symbol like `{__symbolic: 'error', message: 'Symbol reference expected'};` but it also [will be skipped](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/compiler/src/aot/static_reflector.ts#L597-L609) inside `StaticReflector`.

And as far as i know there is currently no solution to support it.

Comment: @David AFAIK angular 5 aot compiler doesn't fix it

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19145

I believe it is the same problem. Decorator inheritance is broken for mixins, so currently you will have to duplicate decorated properties.